# Cordova GeoLocation not working in android app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using cordova plugin geolocation, to fetch user location in IONIC Android app
Code to get location

```
$cordovaGeolocation
        .getCurrentPosition()
        .then(function (position) {
          $scope.map.center.lat  = position.coords.latitude;
          $scope.map.center.lng = position.coords.longitude;
          $scope.map.center.zoom = 18;
          $scope.map.markers.now = {
            lat:position.coords.latitude,
            lng:position.coords.longitude,
            focus: true,            
            draggable: false,
            //message: ''
          };

        }
```

These code doesn't work in android mobile app, debugging shows 'REQUIRED SSL'

As app is running locally, on every mobile, how ssl can be used or is there any other option to get user location in hybrid apps.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this??if so please post the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation) {
   var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
   $cordovaGeolocation
   .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)

   .then(function (position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude
      var long = position.coords.longitude
      console.log(lat + '   ' + long)
   }, function(err) {
      console.log(err)
   });

   var watchOptions = {timeout : 3000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
   var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);

   watch.then(
      null,

      function(err) {
         console.log(err)
      },

      function(position) {
         var lat  = position.coords.latitude
         var long = position.coords.longitude
         console.log(lat + '' + long)
      }
   );

   watch.clearWatch();

})
```

Comment: It worked only one time, to get location again i have to restart app

Comment: Did you get the solution for this??if so please post the answer